A problem with WordPress that creates a white space for itself
As you can see in the pictures, in the editor mode, my single post template is full page, but when outputting, a series of white spaces are created around it. Does anyone have a solution? (It is Astra format) [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/0kLtle9C.png)
I tried almost everything on the internet and it didn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's because your post container has a default padding.

Try using inspect element
Find the container
Address the container with specific classes and ids
add your css snippet into your style.css or output.css or any css file that your website loads it.

An example of css snippet usage for removing default padding:
.your-custom-class {
    padding: 0px;
}

If the css code doesn't remove your container's padding, try use more specific address in hierarchy css template or try using !important after the 0px
